# Add viewcontroller in cocos2d scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Can anyone tell me the best way to add a viewcontroller with nib file to a cocos2d scene?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIView can be added to another UIView but not to cocos2d scene (CCScene). You can use openGLView from CCDirector class for your purpose.

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView addSubView:yourView]
```

Answer (score 3):

actually it is..

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: Im not able to fine openGLView in cocos2d 3.0, can u help me out with this?